# How to kill a respawn service on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, upstart, kill-process

I want to kill a respawn service by using upstart.
when I use "htop" command to monitor system,I observe a process "/123.lock".
when I kill it via "kill" command,it restart again.
how could I kill it via upstart to kill this process totally?
best regards.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely some kind of malware or trojan.

I have just had the same process appear (this morning !) on a quite recently installed Fedora server, along with another executable /init.lock .
Found these while trying to figure what was eating my cpu - and I doubt these files are legit.

I "chmod -x" 'd both of them after killing their processes  (that'll stop it respawning in your case).  Will remove them when I've found out how they got there.